# swf file is not dynamically referring other swf files

Tags: html, flash

I have one website www.gotmilk.com, which is having a full web page flash content.
The very first flash file that is being display is "shell.swf". When I capture the network traffic with etheral , I came to know this "shell.swf" , refers some other files (e.g. main.swf, some .flv and some other .mp3) , in order to make this website works.

Now my question is if I download the complete web page and then try to load it once again using that downloaded webpage , why this is not working.

Form etheral I am able to see that only "shell.swf", got downloaded from server but this file has not been referred any other files.

Answer (score 0):

The file you downloaded most likely refers to the other files from within the SWF file itself.  Simply saving the webpage will not capture these other files.  If you want shell.swf to always load the external files make sure that it refers to these files with static paths (ex: "http://www.gotmilk.com/flash/file.swf") rather than relative ones ("flash/file.swf").

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! your assumption is correct only but the problem is that I am not the creator of the "shell.swf", file so how can I put the full qualified path for the other links referred by this swf file. Please advice.....or is there any html property tag which resolves relative path and query for absolute path accoridngly.?

Comment: Unfortunately the only option would be to get a Flash decompressor of some sort, but otherwise I can't be of too much help.